# OpenGrok: ClearCaseRepository not working (missing binaries?)

Tags: clearcase, opengrok

When starting Catalina run, I get the following warning:

WARNING: ClearCaseRepository not working (missing binaries?):

Any idea, anyone?

Thanks, Avi

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [this thread](http://marc.info/?l=opensolaris-opengrok-discuss&m=129465385517460&w=2) (I will adapt the following extract to your case):

> As far as I can see from the code, this warning can only happen if the command "git --help" [in your case cleartool -version] exits with a non-zero exit code.
>
> What do you see if you log in as the tomcat user, set the `PATH` like you do in `startup.sh`, and then execute following commands

```
cleartool -version
echo $?
```

Check the logs (`catalina.out`) after adding the following line to your Tomcat's `conf/logging.properties`:

```
org.opensolaris.opengrok.level=ALL
```

Comment: I run the OpenGrok on WIN. I tried running the org.opensolaris.opengrok.level=ALL to conf/logging.properties    but stil I get the message:
ClearCaseRepository not working (missing binaries?)     and the history feature doesn't work....